# How is money earned?

Tags: killing-floor

In Killing Floor, how to you earn money? For every zombie killed, do you get a certain amount of money? For each zombie *you* kill, do you get a certain amount of money? Does each type of zombie give different amounts of money? Is the amount of money you get a stable amount that doesn't change (Ex. $500 every round)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of money you earn is dependant on the type of mutant killed and what difficulty you are on.

[The wiki](http://kf-wiki.com/wiki/Specimens#Bounty) has a nice chart of the values.

Also from the wiki:

> Upon killing a specimen, the player is rewarded with a cash bounty.
>   This bounty varies between specimens and difficulties. The base value
>   is the bounty on Normal; for Beginner, this is doubled; for hard and
>   suicidal/hell on earth, the floor values of 85% and 65% (respectively)
>   are used. All values are in British pounds.